# Trifilar pendulum Time period

Tags: differential-geometry, time, moment-of-inertia

The conical frustum for which moment of inertia was calculated using a Trifilar Pendulum is made of wood (density = 0.7 g/cc). If iron is used instead and dimensions of the frustum are kept same, will the time period of oscillation of the pendulum increase?

Comment: What's made of iron? The suspending rods? The oscillating bob? Both?

Comment: What is a trifilar pendulum?